# Create registration for Azure Notification Hub in Postman

Tags: api, rest, postman, azure-notificationhub

I created a Service Bus / Notification Hub in my Azure Portal.

Now I'm trying to use the Azure REST API with **Postman** based on this doc :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223265.aspx

Here is the Postman configuration I have :

It's a **POST** method of the following url (*Create Registration*)
https://mysite.servicebus.windows.net/mysite-notif/registrations/?api-version=2015-01
(I replaced with *mysite* in that url for privacy reasons)

In the **Headers**, I typed 2 entries :

**Content-Type**
application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8

**Authorization**
Endpoint=sb://[mysite].servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=[mykey]
(this Connection information I copied from the Azure portal)

In the **Body**, I chose *raw - XML(txt/xml)* and pasted :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <content type="application/xml">
        <WindowsRegistrationDescription xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect">
            <Tags>myTag, myOtherTag</Tags>
            <ChannelUri>{ChannelUri}</ChannelUri>
        </WindowsRegistrationDescription>
    </content>
</entry>
```

(it's the Native registration for Windows Notification Service example)

When I send this call from within Postman, I get a **401 Error** :

```
<Error>
    <Code>401</Code>
    <Detail>MalformedToken: The credentials contained in the authorization header are not in the WRAP format..TrackingId:ee0d87ef-6175-46a1-9b35-6c31eed6049d_G2,TimeStamp:8/13/2015 9:58:26 AM</Detail>
</Error>
```

What am I missing ?
Is it the Authorization tab I left on "No Auth" in Postman ?
Is it the value of the Authorization header that should be encoded like shown here ?
[Creating registration ID for Azure Notification Hub via REST api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31292156/creating-registration-id-for-azure-notification-hub-via-rest-api)

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your **"Authorization"** header is not correct.

As stated in the [Azure Notification Hubs REST API documentation, e.g. for creating a registration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn223265.aspx), the **"Authorization"** header has to contain the *"Token generated as specified in Shared Access Signature Authentication with Service Bus"*...

The token format is specified in the documentation for [Shared Access Signature Authentication with Service Bus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/Dn170477.aspx) as the following:

```
SharedAccessSignature sig=<signature-string>&se=<expiry>&skn=<keyName>&sr=<URL-encoded-resourceURI>
```

- `URL-encoded-resourceURI`: The url you send the POST request to (in your case "https://mysite.servicebus.windows.net/mysite-notif/registrations/?api-version=2015-01")
- `keyName`: In your case the default key name "DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature"
- `expiry`: The expiry is represented as the number of seconds since the epoch 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970.
- `signature-string`: The signature for the SAS token is computed using the HMAC-SHA256 of a string-to-sign with the PrimaryKey property of an authorization rule. The string-to-sign consists of a resource URI and an expiry, formatted as follows:

  - `StringToSign = <resourceURI> + "\n" + expiry;`
  - `resourceURI` should be the same as `URL-encoded-resourceURI` (also URL encoded)
  - Compute the HMAC-SHA256 of `StringToSign` using the SAS key (what you replaces with [mykey] in your example). Use the URL encoded result for `signature-string` then.

Comment: I used your information to correct my code (which is Javascript in Adobe Campaign/Neolane)
I get a 401 "HTTP header 'WWW-Authenticate' used for proxy authentication not found."
The 4 parameters obtained to build the SharedAccessSignature are :
1) signatureString : 201970e7eaec1c11764c29185575e051a5b447fc63256b319e5bb624677fd8cb
 - 2) expiry : 1441035401.512
 - 3) keyName : DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature
 - 4) URL-encoded-resourceURI : https://mysite-ns.servicebus.windows.net/mysite/registrations/?api-version=2015-01
Does it look correct ? (apparently not though)

Comment: Fix to show full url: URL-encoded-resourceURI : https:// mysite-ns.servicebus.windows.net/mysite/registrations/?api-version=2015-01 (w/o space inside)

Comment: 1. `expiry` should be an integer (you have a dot there). 2. Your URI is not URL encoded (should be this: `https%3A%2F%2Fmysite-ns.servicebus.windows.net%2Fmysite%2Fregistrations%2F%3Fapi-version%3D2015-01`). 3. About the error you get: It seems you have some proxy configured, I don't know how that works, but have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748374/http-401-whats-an-appropriate-www-authenticate-header-value).

Comment: I computed my token based on [Creating registration ID for Azure Notification Hub via REST api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31292156/creating-registration-id-for-azure-notification-hub-via-rest-api) Token : 
**SharedAccessSignature sr=https%3a%2f%2fmyhubnotif-ns.servicebus.windows.net%2fmyhubnotif%2fregistrations%2f%3fapi-version%3d2015-01&sig=91336b70ff4933ebddad687d9350bb0c9b65806a1997750b8b6d78271a185413&se=1449128177&skn=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature** - In Postman, Authorization header with that token returns 401 40103 : Invalid authorization token signature - Still no luck

Comment: Your SAS token looks OK to me. Double check, if you used to correct key and hub.

Comment: I ended up generating the token below in .NET with that [code sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Shared-Access-Signature-0a88adf8) then manually gave it to my Javascript code. The HttpClientRequest went through. I'll come back later to that token/401 issue, thanks -  
SharedAccessSignature sr=https%3a%2f%2fvphubnotif-ns.servicebus.windows.net%2fvphubnotif%2fregistrations%2f&sig=MNhR6Wn%2b2kDaD6Ik6gbbZWrKyAjdKxYZq73NsDOaKkQ%3d&se=1441700857&skn=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature

Comment: @2020 - AzureServiceBus REST API in C# .NET core using HTTPClient - this worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/45055279

Answer (score 17):

Here is an example of a **pre-request script** for **postman** that generates the needed header:

```
function getAuthHeader(resourceUri, keyName, key) {

    var d = new Date();
    var sinceEpoch = Math.round(d.getTime() / 1000);

    var expiry = (sinceEpoch + 3600);

    var stringToSign = encodeURIComponent(resourceUri) + '\n' + expiry;

    var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(stringToSign, key);
    var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);

    var sasToken = 'SharedAccessSignature sr=' + encodeURIComponent(resourceUri) + '&sig=' + encodeURIComponent(hashInBase64) + '&se=' + expiry + '&skn=' + keyName;

    return sasToken;
}

postman.setEnvironmentVariable('azure-authorization', getAuthHeader(request['url'], "mySharedAccessKeyName", "mySharedAccessKey"));
postman.setEnvironmentVariable('current-date',new Date().toUTCString());
```

To use it do the following:

1. add this pre-request script to your postman request
2. replace `mySharedAccessKeyName` , `mySharedAccessKey` with your credentials
3. add a header `Authorization: {{azure-authorization}}`
4. add a header `x-ms-date: {{current-date}}`

Comment: This is not working for me, I get a generic response Publicly Listed Services, no matter what I use. Can you help out?

Comment: Works perfect. Just use setGlobalVariable instead of setEnvironmentVariable if you don't have an environment configuration!

Answer (score 4):

After spending over an hour trying to understand why the steps above didn't work, I realized if you are using the code from https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Shared-Access-Signature-0a88adf8 It has two things that are not defined at the top of the code. Key and KeyName.

The Key is the part that alluded me because at first glance on the other post here I thought it was the same. Its not.

In Azure: Go to your Notification Hub, Then Click  > Settings>  Access Policies then on the Policy that has Manage Permission. Add a policy if you need to. Once you Click on the Access Policy. It shows  Connection String, Primary and Secondary.  Copy the Primary to your Clipboard and throw it in notepad. It will look something like this..

> Endpoint=sb://mysite.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=hc7qZ+pMG6zltjmASDFrskZO+Yv52D55KQUxUTSO0og=

SharedAccessKeyName = KeyName

SharedAccessKey = Key

Yea it looks obvious all spelled out here but you cannot see this information in AZURE portal unless you copy it.

So Just to be totally Clear, in the header you generate the key "sig"  by combining   + "\n" + expiry which Baris did point out, but then you sign it with the Key not the KeyName..

I may sounds like an idiot spelling this out but this process is not an easy one.

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: Oh God I'm an idiot. Thank you for this. I was using the wrong key.

Comment: The SharedAccessKey format you specified here with Endpoint=sb and two keys is valid only when making Azure Service Bus call with sb protocol (native) and not when using its REST APIs. Or you would get error similar to "The credentials contained in the authorization header are not in the WRAP format"

Answer (score 1):

Baris Akar's response is mostly correct, except for one omission that, for whatever reason, is also not mentioned in the [relevant documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-sas#generate-a-shared-access-signature-token): the signature parameter (i.e., the signature-string in sig=) must be Base64 encoded!

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove "\"" in Token String like below.

authorizationString = resultA.replaceAll("\"","");

From
"SharedAccessSignature sr=https%3a%2f%2fmshub.servicebus.windows.net%2f&sig=PFZVab43PMsO0q9gz4%2bFsuaQq%5ff05L4M7hKVBN8DEn0%3d&se=1553339810&skn=RootManageSharedAccessKey"

To
SharedAccessSignature sr=https%3a%2f%2fmshub.servicebus.windows.net%2f&sig=PFZVab43PMsO0q9gz4%2bFsuaQq%5ff05L4M7hKVBN8DEn0%3d&se=1553339810&skn=RootManageSharedAccessKey

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

See the following documentation from Microsoft to generate a SAS Token.
This token you can use in Postman.

[Generate SAS Token (NodeJs, Java, etc.)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token#powershell)

Answer (score 0):

Like Jérôme, I also used the example at https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Shared-Access-Signature-0a88adf8 to generate the token and I also found out that the .NET-generated token worked.  I compared the .NET-generated token with my ruby-generated token and found that URI.escape did not encode the last character (an '=' sign) of my base64 hash.  It also did not encode '+' signs. Adding the string '=+' to the function fixed the problem: **URI.escape(hmacb64, '=+')**
(I don't know if there are other characters that should be identified here.)

Answer (score 0):

It also took me quite some time to figure out a way to generate the SAS tokens in Go.

I created a gist which shows how to generate those tokens:
https://gist.github.com/dennis-tra/14c63e6359f17cbb504e78d6740ca465

I probably wouldn't have figured it out if had not found this repo:
https://github.com/shanepeckham/GenerateSASTokenGo/blob/master/gosas.go

Answer (score 0):

Working from D-rk's code, which is probably outdated in 2022, here's an updated version that works in Postman 10.5.6 and with the Azure Notification Hub's api-version 2020-06

Postman Pre-Request Script:

```js
function createSharedAccessToken(sb_name, eh_name, saName, saKey) {
    if (!sb_name || !eh_name || !saName || !saKey) { 
        throw "Missing required parameter"; 
    } 
    var resourceUri = encodeURIComponent("https://" + sb_name + ".servicebus.windows.net/" + eh_name)

    // Set expiration in seconds
    var expires = (Date.now() / 1000) + 20 * 60;
    expires = Math.ceil(expires);
    var toSign = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(resourceUri + '\n' + expires);

    var sa_key_utf8 = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(saKey);

    var hmac = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(toSign, sa_key_utf8);
    var hmacBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hmac);
    var hmacUriEncoded = encodeURIComponent(hmacBase64);

    // Construct autorization string
    var token = "SharedAccessSignature sr=" + resourceUri + "&sig=" + hmacUriEncoded + "&se=" + expires + "&skn="+ saName;
    return token;
}

var sb_name = "your-notification-hub-namespace";
var eh_name = "your-notification-hub-name";
//See Access Policies -> Connection String
var sa_name = "your-shared-access-key-name"
var sa_key = "your-shared-access-key-name"

var auth_header = createSharedAccessToken(sb_name, eh_name, sa_name,sa_key);

pm.environment.set('azure-authorization',auth_header);
pm.environment.set('current-date',new Date().toUTCString());
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution provided by Dirk helped me to resolve the issue.
But make sure to use SharedAccessKeyName and SharedAccessKey from a policy which has "Manage" claims access. If you have only Send and/or Listen claims, then the authentication will not work and throws an error - MalformedToken: The credentials contained in the authorization header are not in the WRAP format