# Sending a message to a azure service bus queue in .Net Core Core using the REST API

Tags: rest, azure, asp.net-core, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I want to send a message to my Azure Service Bus Queue in .Net Core but the WindowsAzure.ServiceBus Package is not compatible with .Net Core.

Can anyone show me how to send a message to the queue using the REST API?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/send-message-to-queue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the [current client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/) is not .NET Core compatible, the [new client](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet), that is a work in progress, is 100% compatible. The pre-release package will be available on April 3rd and the status can be tracked [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues/49#issuecomment-288882488). You could pull down the course code and compile it already today with the caveat that API will be changing as the team is trying to flesh out the design details.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I am able to send the messages now by installing the nuget package.

Comment: There was an alpha release yesterday on nuget. So now it's a real thing :)

Comment: What if we want to target .NET Core 2.0 or .NETStandard 2?

Comment: It's .NET Standard 1.3 [compliant](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.azure.servicebus), so targeting [.NET Standard 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) or .NET Core 2.0 shouldn't be a problem. BTW, the new client has GA-ed recently, so you could use it for production code.

Comment: This is rather weird that Microsoft puts so much investment in their messaging platforms and offerings, whilst providing so little support for their primary development platform APIs. People who programmed against the "old" client library for years are now stuck. The "new" library is substantially different and there is not even a sign of some sort of migration guide. Go figure out.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev if you refer to the [documentation and guidance](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3Adocumentation), I agree. The difference between the two clients is not that big, but it's there and does require migration.

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone show me how to send a message to the queue using the REST API?

As 4c74356b41 mentioned in his comment, we could send a message to Azure Service Bus queue via [this REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/send-message-to-queue):

`POST http{s}://{serviceNamespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{queuePath|topicPath}/messages`

*here is a example*

[image]

In above request, I provide a Shared Access Signature (token), to generate a Shared Access Signature (token), please refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-sas#generate-a-shared-access-signature-token).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Fred's answer, I've expanded to include how to post the authentication header with signature.

```
public class AzureServiceBusSettings
{
    public string BaseUrl { get; set; }
    public string SharedAccessKey { get; set; }
    public string SharedAccessKeyName { get; set; }
}

public interface IServiceBus
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Publish domain events to domain topic.
    /// </summary>
    Task PublishAsync<T>(T @event)

    /// <summary>
    /// Send commands to command queue.
    /// </summary>
    Task SendAsync<T>(T command)
}

public class ServiceBus : IServiceBus
{
    private readonly AzureServiceBusSettings _settings;

    public ServiceBus(IOptions<AzureServiceBusSettings> azureServiceBusSettings)
    {
        _settings = azureServiceBusSettings.Value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Publish domain events to domain topic.
    /// </summary>
    public async Task PublishAsync<T>(T @event)
    {
        await SendInternalAsync(@event, "domain");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Send commands to command queue.
    /// </summary>
    public async Task SendAsync<T>(T command)
    {
        await SendInternalAsync(command, "commands");
    }

    private async Task SendInternalAsync<T>(T command, string queueName)
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(command);
        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_settings.BaseUrl);

            try
            {
                var url = $"/{queueName}/messages";

                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("SharedAccessSignature", GetSasToken(queueName));

                var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);

                // Success returns 201 Created.
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // Handle this.
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle this.
                // throw;
            }
        }
    }

    private string GetSasToken(string queueName)
    {
        var url = $"{_settings.BaseUrl}/{queueName}";
        // Expiry minutes should be a setting.
        var expiry = (int)DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20).Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;
        var signature = GetSignature(url, _settings.SharedAccessKey);
        var token = $"sr={WebUtility.UrlEncode(url)}&sig={WebUtility.UrlEncode(signature)}&se={expiry}&skn={_settings.SharedAccessKeyName}";
        return token;
    }

    private static string GetSignature(string url, string key)
    {
        var expiry = (int)DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20).Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;
        var value = WebUtility.UrlEncode(url) + "\n" + expiry;
        var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        var keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(key);
        var valueBytes = encoding.GetBytes(value);
        using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyByte))
        {
            var hashmessage = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(valueBytes);
            var result = Convert.ToBase64String(hashmessage);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

And a simple xunit test to post:

```
public class ServiceBusTests
{
    public class FooCommand : ICommand
    {
        public Guid CommandId { get; set; }
    }

    private Mock<IOptions<AzureServiceBusSettings>> _mockAzureServiceBusOptions;

    private ServiceBus _sut;

    public ServiceBusTests()
    {
        var settings = new AzureServiceBusSettings
        {
            BaseUrl = "https://my-domain.servicebus.windows.net",
            SharedAccessKey = "my-key-goes-here",
            SharedAccessKeyName = "RootManageSharedAccessKey"
        };

        _mockAzureServiceBusOptions = new Mock<IOptions<AzureServiceBusSettings>>();
        _mockAzureServiceBusOptions.SetupGet(o => o.Value).Returns(settings);

        _sut = new ServiceBus(
            _mockAzureServiceBusOptions.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task should_send_message()
    {
        // Arrange.
        var command = new FooCommand {CommandId = Guid.NewGuid()};

        // Act.
        await _sut.SendAsync(command);

        // Assert.
        // TODO: Get the command from the queue and assert something.
    }
}
```