# Azure deployment failes due to missing assembly reference

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-deployment

So I have a simple C# Web API project that I'm attempting to get deployed into Azure. The project builds and runs fine locally (dont they always?!?) but in Azure it fails due to a missing Microsoft.ServiceBus assembly which is used.

The project structure is quite simple:

```
\
--\Common
----MyProj.common.dll << This uses Microsoft.ServiceBus and has its own packages.config with WindowsAzure.ServiceBus referenced
--\Web
----MyProj.Api << This has an assembly reference to MyProj.common.dll. It doesn't have a reference to WindowsAzure.ServiceBus itself (although I added one to see if it helped, but it didn't)
```

The output from the Azure deployment script is as follows:

```
 Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling ASP.NET Core Web Application deployment.
  Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\MyProj\Web\MyProj.Api\MyProj.Api.csproj...
  Installing WindowsAzure.ServiceBus 4.0.0.
  Writing lock file to disk. Path: D:\home\site\repository\MyProj\Web\MyProj.Api\obj\project.assets.json
  Restore completed in 12.73 sec for D:\home\site\repository\MyProj\Web\MyProj.Api\MyProj.Api.csproj.

  NuGet Config files used:
      D:\local\AppData\NuGet\NuGet.Config

  Feeds used:
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

  Installed:
      1 package(s) to D:\home\site\repository\MyProj\Web\MyProj.Api\MyProj.Api.csproj
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.548.43366
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\1.0.1\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1964,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\home\site\repository\MyProj\MyProj.Shared\MyProj.Common.csproj]
Azure\AQM.cs(7,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ServiceBus' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\MyProj\MyProj.Shared\MyProj.Common.csproj]

Azure\AQM.cs(8,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ServiceBus' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\MyProj\MyProj.Shared\MyProj.Common.csproj]
Azure\AQM.cs(14,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NamespaceManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\MyProj\MyProj.Shared\MyProj.Common.csproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\1.0.1\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(92,5): error : Cannot find project info for 'D:\home\site\repository\MyProj\MyProj.Shared\MyProj.Common.csproj'. This can indicate a missing project reference. [D:\home\site\repository\MyProj\Web\MyProj.Api\MyProj.Api.csproj]
Failed exitCode=1, command=dotnet publish "MyProj\Web\MyProj.Api\MyProj.Api.csproj" --output "D:\local\Temp\8d493823074840c" --configuration Release
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\62.60430.2807\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

I notice at no point does it attempt to restore the package for the Common assembly - how do I 'tell' Azure to do this? And is this even the issue?

**Edit 1**

Looking at the deployment script using Kudu, it seems to be doing a solution wide restore, so not sure how/why there is a missing assembly reference:

```
:: 1. Restore nuget packages
call :ExecuteCmd dotnet restore "MyProj\MyProj.sln"
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I notice at no point does it attempt to restore the package for the Common assembly - how do I 'tell' Azure to do this? And is this even the issue?

According to your description, your project is .net core project.

You mentioned [Servicebus Libriary](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/4.0.0) (WindowsAzure.ServiceBus 4.0.0)  is not .NET Core compatible. And the new [Libriary](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus/), that is a pre-release version, is 100% compatible. We can get more detail [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet).

We also can find it from another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43030856/sending-a-message-to-a-azure-service-bus-queue-in-net-core-core-using-the-rest?answertab=active#tab-top).

**Edit:**

According to your comment I update the answer:

I also try to create C# Web API project and deploy to Azure it works correctly on my side.

Please have a try to clean the build and rebuild the project again with a new WebApp.

The following is my detail steps:

1.Create a class libiary project named common and a public ServiceBusHelper class  with function GetQueue

[image]

2.Create a WebApp project and reference Common.dll and Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll, then change the getvaules function to get queues

```
 public List<QueueDescription> Get()
        {
            var queueList = Common.ServiceBusHelper.GetQueueList();
            return queueList;
        }
```

3.Remove the existed file from the Auzre WebApp during publish the WebApi to Azure

4.Test the WebApp

[image]

Comment: Sorry Tom, my bad. Its full .net (4.6.2).

Comment: Update the answer, more detail please refer to it.