# Using Azure Notification Hub to push to C# WinForms app

Tags: c#, ios, winforms, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I am currently pushing notifications from my Desktop C# WinForms app to iOS devices. Is it possible to do the same other way around? e.g. Sending notifications from iOS device to WinForms app.

If not possible, what would be the best practices for letting know the WinForms application that iOS app perform certain task(s).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Azure Notification Hub is often used for mobile devices. For Winforms app, I suggest you Azure Service Bus topics service.

On your IOS side, you could send the message to the topic.

```
var connectionString = "<your connection string>";
var topicName = "<your topic name>";

var client = TopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, topicName);
var message = new BrokeredMessage("This is a test message!");

client.Send(message);
```

On your Winform side, you could subscribe the topic and receive messages from the topic. After received the message, you could do anything you want in your Winform application.

```
var connectionString = "<your connection string>";
var topicName = "<your topic name>";

var client = SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, topicName, "<your subscription name>");
client.OnMessage(message =>
{
  Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Message body: {0}", message.GetBody<String>()));
  Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Message id: {0}", message.MessageId));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! This is exactly what I am looking for! Howerver, I have one little problem. Sending messages take too long (~10 seconds). I believe there is a problem but I could not resolve it. I am using the code you posted btw.

Comment: Update: I was able to add Service Bus package to Xamarin.iOS project. However, it does not have any effect. TopicClient is not recognized and does not accept any using statements. Any ideas?

Comment: The Azure Service SDK is not available for Xamarin.iOS project. Please use REST API instead. [Send Message using REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/send-message-to-queue)

Comment: Could you please explain little more on how to implement REST API? Searching for hours to figure it out but I am very confused...

Comment: Please reference the detail code from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45055279/7597097). I just tested the code and it worked OK for me.